# Is it possible to save `bc` command line history?

Tags: gnu, readline, bc

`bash` has a handy file `.bash_history` in which it saves the history of commands and on the next execution of `bash` the history is populated with saved commands.

Is it possible to save `bc` command history to a file in the same way and then load it on startup so that bc history is preserved?

I tried reading [GNU bc manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html#SEC20) and it mentions `readline` and `libedit`. From `ldd /usr/bin/bc` I see mine uses `readline` and `readline` has [`write_history`](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/history.html#IDX29) and `read_history` functions. Is this functionality implemented in `bc` or to do it I'll need to patch `bc`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you aren't happy with the command line editing features that are built into a program, you can run it through [rlwrap](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap). This is a wrapper around a command line processor (a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)) that lets you edit each line before it's sent. Rlwrap uses the readline library and saves history separately for each command.

Running `rlwrap bc` won't do anything for you because rlwrap detects that your `bc` wants to do its own command line editing, so rlwrap turns itself off. Since you do want rlwrap's command line editing features and not the underlying command's, run

```
rlwrap -a bc
```

The command history will be saved in `~/.bc_history`.

The main downside of relying on rlwrap rather than using the program's own readline integration is that rlwrap can't do any context-sensitive completion. For example, the `python` toplevel completes known variables and fields, but `rlwrap python` cannot do that. Since bc doesn't appear to have any custom completion, `rlwrap -a bc` doesn't lose functionality over bc.

Comment: On Arch Linux, `bc` is now compiled with readline support, and does not play nicely with `rlwrap`.  One can either force `bc` to be in noninteractive mode (`rlwrap -a sh -c 'cat | bc'`) or overload the library calls to `readline` to call the read/write functions of `readline/history.h` (quickly implemented [here](https://github.com/michaelcadilhac/readline-force-write-history)).

Answer (score 4):

This method with `tee` works for me. It saves the whole dialogue.

```
$ rm -i bc.log; tee -a bc.log | bc | tee -a bc.log
rm: remove regular file 'bc.log'? y
3*4
12
9*16
144
^C
$ cat bc.log    
3*4
12
9*16
144
$
```

You could also have separate log files for the input and output of `bc`.

The next example shows how only the input is saved, and appended between sessions.

```
$ rm bc.log  # only when you want to clear the log file

$ tee -a bc.log | bc
7+5-2
10
37*27
999
225/3
75
^C
$ cat bc.log
7+5-2
37*27
225/3
$ tee -a bc.log | bc
2^10
1024
^C
$ cat bc.log
7+5-2
37*27
225/3
2^10
$
```